Site.forgotPassword() not sending email to community user
I have a custom Forgot Password page that uses Site.forgotPassword() method to send reset password email to community users. When I use this page in an LWR community site, it is working fine and a reset password email is sent to the user. But When I use the same page with an Aura community site, it is not sending email to the user. I have tested this behaviour from both Preview page and directly from the portal.
If someone has faced a similar issue or has a solution to fix this, please help!
@AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean doForgoPassword(String username){
        try {
            
            // Use Site.login to authenticate the user
            boolean sucess = Site.forgotPassword(username);
            return sucess;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug(loggingLevel.debug +'e.getMessage()'+e.getMessage());
            return false;
            //throw new AuraHandledException('Login failed: ' + e.getMessage());
            
        }
        
    }

